# Usar variable de otra clase

Tags: java

Tengo muchos problemas a la hora de usar getter y setter y sin ejemplos que me ayuden me cuesta entender lo que quiero..

Os explico.

Tengo esta parte mi código :

```
    // Acció button Aceptar
class BtnAceptar implements ActionListener {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Creem les variables que utilitzem per registrar usuaris etc..

        String soapEndpointUrl = "http://gamificacioc.com:80/ServerGIOC/webservices";
        String soapAction = "http://gamificacioc.com:80/ServerGIOC/comprovarLogin";

        //Recollim les dades dels buttons e inicialitzem variables
        String usuari = txtUsuari2.getText(); 
        String usuariContrasenya = textPassword2.getText();

       WebServiceCalls calls = new WebServiceCalls();
       Object authId = null;

        //Exemple sense recollir la info dels  butons ho tinc per probar directament sense recollir dels buttons
       // System.out.println(calls.comprovarLogin("fbarcia", "password"));

       //Recollin't la info dels buttons.
        SoapObject resposta = calls.comprovarLogin(usuari, usuariContrasenya);
         if (resposta == null)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error falten dades");
         }

         else
         {
             //Si els buttons son plens verifica que sigui correcte
            authId= resposta.getPrimitiveProperty("authId");
            //authId ens dona el resultat que volem pasar per saber el tipus User

         //Enviem l'authId per poder saber que usuari es...         
         String resposta2 = calls.tipusUsuari(authId.toString()); 
         System.out.println(authId);
```

El tema es que necesito recuperar el authId para usarlo en otra clase, pero me gustaría que no fuera con una variable global y no sé como hacerlo..

Podéis ayudarme a entender?

gracias

Comment: y como tienes la clase que tiene la propiedad authId?? sería algo como public class Author() { public authId {get; set} } luego instancias y llamas el objeto con authId

Comment: @ger el ejemplo que pones es de .Net en java los getter and setter no se hacen así, se han de crear "funciones" get and set

Comment: A ver, hay errores de conceptos, dices que no la quieres hacer global, por tanto no podrás tener los getter and setters. Por tanto, lo que puedes hacer, es que tu método cuando acabe la ejecución haga un return de la variable.

Comment: @EduBw el método esta implementando (no se el por que de @override)) a un método de ActionListener, por lo cual no puede hacer return ya que dejaría de sobreescribir

Comment: El override te obliga a ponerlo porque estás trayendo los métodos del ActionListener, que no sé si serán suyos o de una api. Independientemente de eso, "pienso", "creo" que puedes hacertelo con un return, cambiando el void, y se convertiría en un método sobrecargado.

Comment: @EduBw no se trae los metodos los implementa por lo cual es una interface `implements ActionListener` (en caso de heredar los métodos sería '`extends ActionListener` y has de cumplir el contrato que estipula la interface. Thks :)

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que sacar la propiedad authId del método y ponerla como privada en la clase y hay crear un getter quedando tu código más o menos así.

```
  // Acció button Aceptar
class BtnAceptar implements ActionListener {
    private Object authId = null;

    public Object getAuthId() {
       return this.authId;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Creem les variables que utilitzem per registrar usuaris etc..

        String soapEndpointUrl = "http://gamificacioc.com:80/ServerGIOC/webservices";
        String soapAction = "http://gamificacioc.com:80/ServerGIOC/comprovarLogin";

        //Recollim les dades dels buttons e inicialitzem variables
        String usuari = txtUsuari2.getText(); 
        String usuariContrasenya = textPassword2.getText();

       WebServiceCalls calls = new WebServiceCalls();

        //Exemple sense recollir la info dels  butons ho tinc per probar directament sense recollir dels buttons
       // System.out.println(calls.comprovarLogin("fbarcia", "password"));

       //Recollin't la info dels buttons.
        SoapObject resposta = calls.comprovarLogin(usuari, usuariContrasenya);
         if (resposta == null)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error falten dades");
         }

         else
         {
             //Si els buttons son plens verifica que sigui correcte
            this.authId= resposta.getPrimitiveProperty("authId");
            //authId ens dona el resultat que volem pasar per saber el tipus User

         //Enviem l'authId per poder saber que usuari es...         
         String resposta2 = calls.tipusUsuari(authId.toString()); 
         System.out.println(authId);
```

Pudiendo obtener el valor de authId desde el getter de la siguiente manera `btnAceptar.getAuthId()`

Comment: Buenas,precisamente dice el autor que no la quiere como una variable global.

Comment: @EduBw es imposible acceder a la propiedad authId de la función si no es global y desea seguir implementando (no se el por que de @override)) la fn

Comment: Una variable global es una variable que puede ser accedida desde cualquier ámbito de la aplicación. En este caso que ha puesto osiris85 no es una variable global, es un atributo privado de la clase, por lo que solo podrá ser accedido directamente desde esa clase, por lo que no se puede considerar variable global. Por lo que esta respuesta, a mi parecer, es correcta.